# array deleted or corrupted

Tags: c++, ios, arrays

I create an array with:

```
MyClass *myInstance = new MyClass[1];
```

then I fill my class with data.
After that, I expand the array like this:

```
MyClass *tempList = new MyClass[myCount+1];
tempList[0] = myInstance[0];
myInstance=tempList;
```

and I fill the data from index 1 to myCount.

After that I call a function with a callback. Before the call all the data is correct, and at the start of the callback function, the data is lost and I get a `EXC_BAD_ADDRESS`. The variable is a private variable, hence it can't be accessed from outside of the class. Which means that it can't be changed from the functions that will call the callback function.

The filling only consists in setting variables of MyClass. But the whole reference to the class seems to be lost.

The project is a cross-platform iOS/Android project, which is being programmed with C++ and tested with XCode.

Am I doing something wrong?

**UPDATE:**

I've redone it with std::vector, now it looks like this:

in the .h I define:

```
std::vector<MyClass*> myInstances;
```

in the .m:
I add 1 element

```
myInstances.push_back(new MyClass());
```

then I fill the variables within myClass. After that I expand myInstances like this:

```
MyClass *tempInstance = myInstances[currentPlayerIndex];
myInstances.clear();
myInstances.push_back(tempInstance);
for (int i=1; i<friends->count()+1; i++)
{
    myInstances.push_back(new MyClass());
    //filling variables, like f.e. myInstances[i]->setScore(1000);
}
```

I'm still getting the same error, exactly at the same point :(

Comment: You're going to need to provide more code, ideally an [sscce](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: `myInstance=tempList;` without deleting the allocated memory by `MyClass *myInstance = new MyClass[1];` => memory leak.

Comment: `myInstance=tempList;` nice memory leak, you forgot to `delete[] myInstance;` before (_edit: slow me ^^_). By the way, what about using a `std::vector<MyClass>`?

Comment: How does the callback find the array?

Comment: Wait, you say "I expand the array" - you're not expanding it. tempList is a NEW array, which you copy element[0] of the previous array into, and then you leak away the previous array (myInstance = tempList doesn't copy/transfer the array, it just changes what data myInstance points to). You should look into std::vector

Comment: Ok, I got confused there, I thought I was setting the element 0 to the address of myInstance 0. I added delete [] myInstance.

Comment: @AlanStokes The callback function is in the same class as the private variable myInstance. `MyClass *myInstance;` is actually defined in the .h

Comment: I will try to implement it with `std:vector<MyClass>`. But I don't understand why I'm getting the `EXC_BAD_ADDRESS`, everything seems ok (but the thing with element 0, which is now fixed)

Comment: It would help a lot if you showed us the callback function itself (and, ideally, how you arrange for it to be called back).

Comment: @AlanStokes I use a library which communicates with facebook (the library is from EziByte). I set myClass as delegate of that library (with `EziSocialObject::sharedObject()->setFacebookDelegate(this);`), the library downloads a facebook avatar and calls `virtual void fbUserPhotoCallback(const char *userPhotoPath);` which is part of myClass. It should not have any impact on the vector. However, the vector is deleted or corrupted whithin the callback. The download is started with `EziSocialObject::sharedObject()->getProfilePicForID(tempTournamentPlayers[0]->getFBID(), 70, 70, true);`

Comment: I actually print out a list of FBIDs before the callback, and it shows all. I do the same as the first line and I get the error at the first index. I am completely clueless...

Comment: I just tested, no function from MyClass is called between the calling of getProfilePicForID and the callback. And since the variable is private, nothing can be changing it. Which means that I am allocating the memory wrong or too weak.. somehow. I only use the code you see in the question with the vector, is it possible that with that code the vector get deleted deallocated or something??

Comment: Also, The class that contains the vector with the MyClass instances works as a singleton. In case that could make any difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MyClass *myInstance = new MyClass[1];
// myInstance is a pointer variable which contains
// an address. It points to a memory location at which
// we have an array of ONE MyClass.

MyClass *tempList = new MyClass[myCount+1];
// creates a NEW allocation, without touching the original.
// tempList is now also a pointer variable. It contains
// an address, the address of a different memory location
// at which we now have 2 myClass instances. This is
// NOT the same location.

tempList[0] = myInstance[0];
// the MyClass instances at *myInstance and *tempList
// are now copies of each other, but only the first instances.

myInstance=tempList;
// myInstance is now pointing to tempList, but the array
// of MyClass instances that it pointed to are still
// allocated. Unfortunately, you no-longer have the
// address stored in any variables. This is called a leak.
```

You should consider looking into one of the STL containers such as [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [std::list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list). If you need to use dynamic allocation, consider using a std::vector. See [std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).

Edit:

You say in comments that you are calling

```
EziSocialObject::sharedObject()->setFacebookDelegate(this);
```

This calls setFacebookDelegate with the address of the *specific* instance you call it from. You also say that it is operating as a singleton, but you are allocating multiple instances of it.

```
MyClass* a = new MyClass;
MyClass* b = new MyClass; // No-longer a singleton.

EziSocialObject::sharedObject()->setFacebookDelegate(a);
// From this point on, a->fbUserPhotoCallback will be called.
```

A preliminary glance at the code suggests that it may be threaded - it has a manager system to handle multiple, potentially concurrent or overlapping requests, and I certainly wouldn't want my game stalling out every time facebook is slow to respond to a refresh request.

I'm still not clear why you need the vector at all -- you seem to have all the data stored somewhere else, and you only actually need the one vector entry, it's only function seems to be to get data from some other class and make it available to "MyClass", but it seems you should be able to do that thru a bridge or lookup class, e.g. a `std::map<std::string /*FaceBookID*/, size_t localID>` or `std::map<std::string /*FaceBookID*/, RealClass*>`.

You might try the following:

```
// enable asserts -- only affects debug build.
#include <assert.h>

// Add a counter to track when we clear the vector,
// and track what the count was last time we called getFacebookPhoto
size_t g_vectorClears = 0;

static const size_t VECTOR_NOT_IN_USE = ~0;
size_t g_vectorUsed = VECTOR_NOT_IN_USE;

// When we clear the vector, check if we are using it.
    assert(g_vectorUsed == VECTOR_NOT_IN_USE);
    ++g_vectorClears;
    g_myInstances.clear();

// When you call getFacebookPhoto, store which clear we were on
    g_vectorUsed = g_vectorClears;
    blah->getFacebookPhoto(...);

// In MyClass->fbUserPhotoCallback, validate:
...
fbUserPhotoCallback(...)
{
    assert(g_vectorUsed == g_vectorClears);
    ...
    // at the end, set g_vectorUsed back to NOT_IN_USE.
    g_vectorUsed = VECTOR_NOT_IN_USE;
}
```

If the plugin is NOT threaded, then the remaining possibility is that somewhere you are passing the address of the vector or the vector's data and you are clobbering it, or that the plugin has a memory leak which is causing it to stomp your vector.

To assist further, you'll need to include more of your code.

Comment: All that is correct, but it does not answer the question about the "bad access".

Comment: I've redone it with `std::vector`, and posted an update to the question with the new code.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what this code is supposed to do. When you "clear" the vector, all of the previous "new"s of MyClass continue to take up memory, but you no-longer have pointers to them. You then proceed to allocate new ones. C++ has no garbage collection, so those objects are being leaked. The problem also seems to revolve around the callback, which you don't include. It sounds like you are having a null pointer issue with the callback, possibly its arguments.

I've made a live demo at ideone.com: http://ideone.com/AQjyxC. Fundamentally the callback is not the problem.

Comment: @MartinR I can't tell what the code is actually supposed to do, and he didn't include the most important part which is the callback itself. Coupled with his confusion and some really bad C++ code practices, it's obfuscated enough that I'm not able to tell what he thinks he's *trying* to do. It seems like some very, very simple patterns could be used to replace it, but without any notion of the outlying system it's hard to tell which is appropriate.

Comment: HTH: In particular, I don't understand why you want to keep clearing the array.

Comment: @kfsone What I want to do is create an array with initially one item, then fill it with a list that will come from a web service. The list may or may not have been filled before and I have to delete previous entries. But I always want to keep the first item.

Comment: Ok - you might want to consider using a `std::vector<MyClass>` directly instead of going thru a pointer. http://ideone.com/Hb9lCf Still - to help with the outlying invalid access problem, you're going to need to show us what and how you are doing the callback, as that is the only remaining source of corruption.

Comment: @kfsone I have also tried that method. I even tried to use a CCArray. See the comments at the questions to see how the method and the callback work. But it should not have any impact on the vector, since it does have no access. The only difference is that it make take some time, and I have the feeling that the Objects are set to autorelease somehow...

Comment: a) Are you sure the Ezi interface is not threaded? b) you say in the comments that MyClass works as a singleton - but you have multiple of them allocated, which means it is NOT a singleton. You have to pass the api *an* instance of MyClass to use as a delegate. Which one are you passing it? I'll add some additional code suggestions to my answer.

Comment: @kfsone Oops, not MyClass is a singleton, but the enclosing class. The class that contains the vector with MyClass instances (sorry, my bad)

Comment: @kfsone I am passing the class that contains the vector as delegate

Comment: Ok; well I've already demonstrated that the code you've shown so far is NOT the source of the problem (see the ideone links). That leaves the code we can't see, and aside from a few comments on what it roughly does, there's just not enough to be able to help you.